# Can I connect the ST Nucleo-F334R8 board using CAN (Controller Area Network)?

Tags: arm, can, mbed, cortex-m4, nucleo

I have the ST Nucleo F334R8 board (64 pin version/LQFP64). The datasheet of its microcontroller (STM32F334R8T6), which is advertised as having one CAN interface - the 2.0 B Active type says this regarding 4 of the microcontroller's pins (on the sub-topic of 'Alternate functions'): CAN_RX (pins PA11 and PB8) and CAN_TX (pins PA12 and PB9).

However, I can't really find anything in the datasheet of the board concerning Controller Area Network. Can I use the CAN interface of the microcontroller or not? I would like to connect the Nucleo-F334R8 to a different board using CAN (in the first instance and LIN afterwards). Can I do that by using just a couple of CAN transceivers (MCP2551)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use the CAN interface of the microcontroller or not?

It depends on yourself.

> I would like to connect the Nucleo-F334R8 to a different board using
>   CAN (in the first instance and LIN afterwards). Can I do that by using
>   just a couple of CAN transceivers (MCP2551)?

I don't know what's another board but for your Nucleo-F334R8 you only need a CAN transceivers (MCP2551).

Bear in mind that there are some software and Libs for using the peripherals of STM32. like:

[CMX-CANopen
CANopen Industrial Automation for STM32, from CMX Systems Inc](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF257442)

and

[STM32CubeF3](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF260613)

and

[STM32CubeMX](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF259242)

you can see all of them [here](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1576/LN1820/PF259916#)(see `All` tab). use them for your job. that will help you to do your job quickly. I myself use them for operating the CAN interface.

Good luck!

Comment: I also have a Tiva-C Series TM4C123GXL LaunchPad. I only want to set up a basic CAN connection between the two boards (using two MCP2551), in order to learn how CAN works.
The CMX-CANopen CANopen Industrial Automation for STM32, from CMX Systems Inc software, is that proprietary? Do I need to pay in order to be able to use it?
The STM32CubeF3 folder contained a CAN HAL module driver (stm32f3xx_hal_can C file).
In regard to the Nucleo board, would that file suffice for testing a simple dialogue between the two boards (the TivaWare C Series examples contain simple_rx + simple_tx C files)?

Comment: @AlexDumitrescu Yes, you need to pay in order to be able to use "CANopen Industrial Automation". I have never had a Nucleo board but I always use STM32 and myself used stm32f3xx_hal_can for use CAN peripheral of STM32 and I think there isn't any problem to use it for your board. "would that file suffice for testing a simple dialogue between the two boards" sure, why not. party on :)